# Can LOAD TABLE be used without a column-list?

Tags: sap-iq

I'm used to unloading and loading data using Sybase ASE using the bcp command-line tool.  This doesn't require you to specify any column names.

I understand that the equivalent to bcp in Sybase IQ is the LOAD TABLE command, however I cannot get any data to load without specifying the column names.

```
datafile.txt:
1,2,3,
1,2,3,

CREATE TABLE myTable (
   fa integer null,
   fb integer null,
   fc integer null
)

LOAD TABLE myTable
FROM 'datafile.txt'
QUOTES OFF 
ESCAPES OFF
```

The above yields the following error;

```
The LOAD statement's column count(0) must be between 1 and 0.  Check the LOAD statement's 'load-specification'
```

I've seen a few examples of the LOAD TABLE command without a column-list, but I cannot get it to work.  Is it only possible with binary files? I've also tried using FORMAT BCP without luck.

It seems mad that column names are a MUST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IQ the LOAD-statement needs a column-list. E.g. from [15.3 documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1530/doc/html/san1281564935243.html):

> The LOAD TABLE command must contain at least one column that needs to be loaded from the file specified in the LOAD TABLE command. Otherwise, an error is reported and the load is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

I use a perl wrapper for 'load table' in IQ (or bcp for Sybase or sqlldr for Oracle). No column list needed if the file matches the table:

```
#/usr/local/bin/perl

use DBIx::BulkUtil;

#...

my ($dbh,$dbu) = DBIx::BulkUtil->iq_connect(
  Server   => $server,
  Database => $db,
  User     => $user,
  Password => $pw,
);

$dbu->bcp_in('mytable', 'datafile.txt', {
  Delimiter => ",",
});
```